# my code for remove @user and punctuation does not work

Tags: python, nlp

I wrote the code below for tweets data set, I want to do preprocessing, I have removed #, website  but my code for remove @user and punctuation does not work ,im new to python can any one help me?

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import spacy, re

nlp = spacy.load('en')

stop_words = [w.lower() for w in stopwords.words()]

def sanitize(input_string):
    """ Sanitize one string """

    # normalize to lowercase 
    string = input_string.lower()

    # spacy tokenizer 
    string_split = [token.text for token in nlp(string)]

    # in case the string is empty 
    if not string_split:
        return '' 

    names = re.compile('@[A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]+')
    string = [re.sub(names, '@USER', tweet) for tweet in input_string()]

    #remove # and @
    for punc in '":!#':
       string = string.replace(punc, '')

    # remove 't.co/' links
    string = re.sub(r'http//t.co\/[^\s]+', '', string, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    # removing stop words 
    string = ' '.join([w for w in string.split() if w not in stop_words])

#punctuation
   # string = [''.join(w for w in string.split() if w not in #string.punctuation) for w in string]



    return string 


list = ['@Jeff_Atwood Thank you for #stackoverflow', 'All hail @Joel_Spolsky t.co/Gsb7V1oVLU #stackoverflow' ]

list_sanitized = [sanitize(string) for string in tweets[:300]]
list_sanitized[:50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex needs to be fixed. Try something like:

```py
names = re.compile('@[A-Za-z0-9_]+')
string = re.sub(names, '@USER', input_string)
```

`input_string` is a variable and not a function, it's also a singular string so you don't want to traverse over it. This will work just fine shown here: https://regexr.com/55u44

Your punctuation removal works just fine, see: https://ideone.com/zScVPJ

Comment: thank you do you know how should I FIX MY PUNCTUATIN?

Comment: i have solve it,     names = re.compile('@[A-Za-z0-9_][A-Za-z0-9_]+') , it should be like this , the rest is ok

Comment: @eli whether you add two groups or one it's the same, if you want two or more groups, use {2,} instead. There's no problem with the punctuation afaics.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
string = [names.sub('@USER', tweet) for tweet in input_string()]

Comment: It because of the input_string() you call it as function , remove the (), i assume you want to do : input_string.split()

Comment: I HAVEE SOLVED BY MY SELF, IT IS like this:     string = re.sub(names, '@USER', input_string)

Comment: Can you please share an example input and desire output?